# Importing a .dot graph file, and changing vertex label format

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, dot

I worked out how (one way...) to import a `.dot` graph format file into Mathematica using

```
Import["/home/username/Desktop/mygraph.dot"]
```

which works a treat, drawing a nice graph with vertices and edges all joined up.

But can anyone please explain how I can make the vertex labels either bigger, or add a coloured background to the label text?

I have many edges between vertices and as it is the thin black small text is difficult to read.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `Graph`options during `Import`ing. That is, if `example.dot` is the file to be imported

```
Export["example.dot", Import["ExampleData/sample.gv"], "DOT"]
```

> "example.dot"

you can import it as follows

```
Import["example.dot", ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 400, 
  VertexLabelStyle -> 16, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

to get

[image]

This feature is documented in [DOT >> Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/DOT.html):

[image]

Alternatively, if you already imported the graph, you can use `SetProperty` to make changes in any of the `Graph` options:

```
g2 = Import["example.dot"]
```

[image]

```
SetProperty[g2, {VertexLabelStyle -> 16, EdgeStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
  ImageSize -> 400, ImagePadding -> 30}]
```

[image]